# Enum inheritance explanation is not clear?

Tags: java, enums

So according to the [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

> All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Because a class can only extend one parent, the Java language does not support multiple inheritance of state, and therefore an enum cannot extend anything else.

But in java we also know:-

> All classes in Java extend java.lang.Object class implicitly

But we can obviously extend Classes in java. Since the class we extend is itself extending from `Object` (hence it does not cause multiple inheritance, Or state it as:- If you do not extend any other class extend from `Object` else extend from class `XYZ` that extends from `Object`)

Is the explanation of the java docs incorrect for the fact that Enums are not able to extend other classes/enums etc?

Am I missing some silly point?

Comment: What would be incorrect about the docs? It seems perfectly clear to me and you understand it too as far as I can tell.

Comment: so where do you see inconsistency? YourEnum extends (implicitly) `java.lang.Enum` which extends `java.lang.Object` however you cannot extend YourEnum further.

Comment: The silly point you are missing is `java.lang.Enum` extends `Object`.

Comment: I think the docs should better say something like "a class can only extend one *direct* parent".

Comment: @kapep hint: consider the difference between parent and ancestor. So any class can extend one parent but many ancestors.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon you're right i went through the docs and got confused forgetting the fact java.lang.Enum extends from java.lang.Object :)

Comment: @SergeyPauk I know, but in many other contexts that difference is not made and any ancestor is considered _a_ parent of a contained element. It might not be correct but I've seen it often enough to understand that reading it like this in the docs might be confusing to some.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply means that *you* can not let your enums extend anything else than the implicitly extended `Enum`.

When it says Java does not allow extending multiple classes, it means that you can't have

```
.--------.   .----------.
| Enum   |   | YourBase |
'--------'   '----------'
     ^            ^
      \          /
        \       /
       .----------.
       | YourEnum |
       '----------'
```

THIS on the other hand, is entirely ok:

```
.--------.
| Object |
'--------'
     ^
     |
.--------.
|  Enum  |
'--------'
     ^
     |
.----------.
| YourEnum |
'----------'
```

When the documentation says

> All classes in Java extend java.lang.Object class implicitly

It simply means that each class either extends Object directly, or indirectly through it's super class.

Comment: Thanks ,I knew it would be something silly. Did not consider the fact that `java.lang.Enum` itself extends from `java.lang.Object` :)

Comment: @aioobe could I ask how do you get this pretty infographic? Is it handwritten or do you use some tool?

Comment: Haha.. It's handwritten. No tool could ever achieve such perfection ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Run this code and you'll get the answer:

```
System.out.println(MyEnum.class.getSuperclass());
System.out.println(MyEnum.class.getSuperclass().getSuperclass());

public enum MyEnum  {   
}
```

Output:

```
class java.lang.Enum
class java.lang.Object
```

And on top of that consider that multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java. I.e. `MyEnum` already extends `Enum` while `Enum` already extends `Object`. There's no room for any other extension in this chain.